# Multires modifier destroys shading but only when sculpting

Tags: texturing, shaders, sculpting, multiresolution

Does anyone knows why does this happens?

I successfully apply Multires subdivisions when I am on Layout mode, but the same modifier destroys shading? UVs? Textures? when applied in Sculpt mode.
Any idea on why?

[image]